# Changing keys appearing on the final pdf

Tags: bibtex

My current state is

> [image]

and I would like to change this appearance of cites with a single number to three characters juxtaposed with two numbers, each of which denotes authors and years of a paper, as follows:

> [image]

I wonder how to do this, and any comment would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `\bibiographystyle{alpha}`.

Comment: That's an alphabetic style, but how to change to it, depends on how you are handling cite and bibliography now. So show a small complete document.

Comment: @DavidPurton if you try that you'll be disappointed :) an `l` is missing (in _biblio_).

Comment: @Marijn, oops! it's usually the b key that causes me grief...

Comment: @DavidPurton Yes, it works. Thanks!